# Rails: Why "sudo" command is not recognized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sudo, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

In my application directory (on Windows) I run:

```
sudo pdfkit --install-wkhtmltopdf
```

as explained [here](http://blog.10to1.be/rails/2010/08/18/pdfkit-and-ruby-on-rails/), but I got this error:

> 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
>       operable program or batch file.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Sudo is a Unix specific command designed to allow a user to carry out administrative tasks with the appropriate permissions.

Windows does not have (need?) this.

Run the command with the sudo removed from the start.

Comment: I tried to run `pdfkit --install-wkhtmltopdf` but now the `pdfkit` command is not recognized. `gem list` shows that I do have the `pdfkit` gem installed. Any ideas ?

Comment: It sounds like PDFkit is not in your PATH. Try navigating to the gem directory and running it from there.

Answer (score 10):

`sudo` is a Unix/Linux command. It's not available in Windows.

Answer (score 5):

sudo is used for Linux.  It looks like you are running this in Windows.

Answer (score 4):

That you are running Windows. Read:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

It basically allows you to execute an application with elevated privileges. If you want to achieve a similar effect under Windows, open an administrative prompt and execute your command from there. Under Vista, this is easily done by opening the shortcut while holding Ctrl+Shift at the same time.

That being said, it might very well be possible that your account already has sufficient privileges, depending on how your OS is setup, and the Windows version used.

Comment: Please see my comment above. `pdfkit --install-wkhtmltopdf` doesn't work either. Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1):

sudo is a command for Linux so it cant be used in windows so you will get that error

Answer (score 0):

> Sudo is a Unix specific command designed to allow a user to carry out administrative tasks with the appropriate permissions.
> Windows doesn't not have (need?) this.

Yes, windows don't have `sudo` on its terminal. Try using `pip` instead.

1. Install `pip` [using the steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-can-i-install-pip-on-windows).
2. type `pip install [package name]` on the terminal. In this case, it may be `pdfkit` or `wkhtmltopdf`.

Answer (score 0):

Analogue to *sudo* in Windows is running command prompt "As Administrator" by right-clicking on it's link. Then everything you run in it will be "*sudo-ed*".

Answer (score 0):

sudo is not for windows, its for unix/linux.

option 1: install ubuntu cli software (not OS) in windows, here is the windows store link: `https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/ubuntu-2004/9n6svws3rx71`. After installing you can use ubuntu's cli in your windows where sudo will work.

option 2: install and use gem (ruby on rails) for installing wkhtmltopdf-binary
`gem install pdfkit`
`gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary`

ref: https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit

option 3: you can use npm or python for wkhtmltopdf insted of ruby on rails, both modules (nodeJS python) works fluently and compatible with windows:-

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf

https://pypi.org/project/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 0):

Windows itself doesn't support `sudo`. However, with [gsudo](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo#installation) installed you can have this functionality. Running `sudo` in this case will call out a UAC prompt.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Install sudo from ***powershell*** in windows.**

Step 1:

> Open Windows Powershell

Step 2: Set Execution Policy

```
> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Step 3: Install scoop

```
>iex "& {$(irm get.scoop.sh)} -RunAsAdmin"
```

Step 4: Install sudo command

```
> scoop install sudo
```

Step 5: Congrats Sudo installation done check with one basic command

```
>sudo`enter code here`
```